# Django use only one column of Model1 as a foreign key in second model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have two Django Models (Events and GMSEvents).

I want to use the eventAcronym of Events model as a foreign key in GMSEvents.
I tried as below, but I get the error

```
AssertionError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002032DA1E8C8>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model,
 a model name, or the string 'self'
```

## Models

```
class Events(models.Model):
    eventAcronym = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False, null=False)
    eventName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.eventAcronym} - {self.eventName}"


class GMSEvents(models.Model):
    gateNo = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    aircraftName = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    detectEvent = models.ForeignKey(Events.eventAcronym, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

update:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mark the `eventAcronym` as *unique*, otherwise it does not per se refers to a unique element:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    eventAcronym = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    # …
```

then you can make use of the [**`to_field=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) to specify the target column:

```
class GMSEvents(models.Model):
    gateNo = models.IntegerField()
    aircraftName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    detectEvent = models.ForeignKey(
        Events,
        to_field='eventAcronym',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **primary_key=True** to eventAcronym field.
**detectEvent = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE)**

```
 class Events(models.Model):
        eventAcronym = models.CharField(max_length=4, primary_key=True)
        eventName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.eventAcronym} - {self.eventName}"

    class GMSEvents(models.Model):
    gateNo = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    aircraftName = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    detectEvent = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: because we changed primary key in Events models. Now you don't need to it models.ForeignKey(Events.eventAcronym. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `ForeignKey` field should be the model class that you would like to relate, not the specific field (i.e. `Events` instead of `Events.eventAcronym`). Django will automatically use the primary key of that model as the foreign key column:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    # add `primary_key=True` here if you don't want to use the implicit ID field
    eventAcronym = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False, null=False)
    eventName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)


class GMSEvents(models.Model):
    gateNo = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    aircraftName = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    detectEvent = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

For reference, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey